# Lazy Construction of a Component

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, architecture

I want to create an Object with this requirement :

1. The Object should be unique, one instance
2. The Object components (fields) will be initialised in different parts of my code, not just in one place.

How can I Implement this ? Using Singleton or Builder or another design pattern.

Thanks

Comment: I'll edit my ans if you're confused at some point. Just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use single `object` throughout, use **`Singleton`** pattern,

If you want to initialize fields from different part from your code, use **`setter`** methods for that field.

> For the point 1, i would suggest you to go with **`Singleton`** pattern.

Comment: Access to setter and getter of mutable singleton fields need synchronisation as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Singleton. Use an `enum` to represent a Singleton. For mutable fields, the access to read and write should be synchronised. Or you could look into `AtomicReference`, or other atomic implementation from `java.util.concurrent` package.

For example:-

```
enum Singleton{

    INSTANCE("Value");

    private final String value;
    private String otherValue;

    Singleton(String val){
       value = val;
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        //actions
    }

    public synchronized void setOtherValue(String value){
        this.otherValue = value;
    }

    public synchronized String getOtherValue(){
         return otherValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For single object creation you can restrict your class to make more than one object by create private constructor 
Example:

```
class Test 
{ 

    private static Test single_instance = null; 

    public String s; 

    private Test() 
    { 
        s = "example"; 
    } 

    public static Test getInstance() 
    { 
        if (single_instance == null) 
            single_instance = new Test(); 

        return single_instance; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Above code is not a safe singleton. If 2 or more threads executed at the if statement check, possibly 2 or more `Test` instances created.